# How to select which Visual Studio version is launched for a .vcproj file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-shell

We are still using VS2005 for C++ development (upgrading *is* planned!) The problem is we also have VS2010 shell installed to work with TFS. If I double-click a .SLN file, VS2005 launches correctly, but if I double-click a .vcproj file VS2010 is launched even though since it's only the shell, it has no way to open the project!

I understand there is a special launcher-version tool involved here, how can I tell it to launch VS2005 in all cases?

Comment: Hi...cant you just right click on the .vcproj and from the open with menu choose default program and choose your VS2005 version ? don't forget to tick the Always use the selected program to open this kind of file ... you can also tell the Visual Studio version selector to open the file with the suitable application for you...

Comment: If you right-click, you don't see VS at all, only the VS version selector. This tool seems to be incorrectly opening the newest VS version, I want to tell it to prefer VS2005.

Comment: hi ..ok try to restore the File Associations in VS2005...in VS2012 I can do that by going into :
Tools->Options->Environment->Manage File Associations
Then choose which files to open with VS2005...Ijust looked into VS2005..the button is marked as "Restore File Associations"

Comment: The .vcproj filename extension is not associated with Visual Studio, it activates the VSLauncher.exe utility.  Which looks at the .vcproj file, checks the version number and then starts the appropriate version of VS.  Hard to guess how that got broken on your machine.  Compare the registry keys to a good machine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this reliably is to run vcvarsall.bat from the desired version of VS